# Keras custom loss - operation on additional data

Tags: neural-network, regression, keras, loss-function

I am trying to create a custom loss function for a Keras regression task.

I am predicting the points scored per minute in a game, and training on "matches" of variable lengths, in minutes. In an attempt to help the model learn, I would like to include the number of minutes the group played as part of the loss function, so we can properly "punish" for missing on groups that play for longer durations.

I know I need to use Keras Backend/tensor operations, but I'm stuck on how to prepare the minutes/how to multiply the minutes tensor. Here's some basic code what I have so far (pseudo code/skipped where not important):

```
def penalized_loss(minutes):

    # minutes is np.array - do we need to convert to tensor?
    #    Is this useful/how to do it?
    minutes_tensor = K.constants(minutes) 

    def loss(y_true, y_pred):

        # Normal mean_squared_error - this makes sense to me
        lost = K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)

        # Would like something like this where minutes are included, but as a valid tensor operation
        not_valid_result = K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true) * minutes, axis=-1)

        # Is this closer to what we need to do?
        maybe_closer_result = K.mean(K.dot(K.square(y_pred - y_true), minutes),  axis=-1)

        return lost

    return loss

# minutes is np.array, shape (12024,)
# input/predictions also have shape 12024

def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    # Create the model....

    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss=[penalized_loss(minutes)], optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

The closure to pass in minutes works as I expect, I'm just stuck on how to do the `* minutes` portion of the loss calculation. I've looked through the docs and I feel like I'm missing something easy/obvious. Can anyone point me in the right direction?